# Change memory content of FPGA SoC (DE1-SoC) using software while .sof (EPCQ) is running on FPGA

Tags: fpga, linux, hdl, soc, cyclone

I am new to FPGA and FPGA-SoC world. I have a DE1-SoC board. I am doing a project. Hardware design of the project contains a memory block which is initialized using .mif file. I know that we can use assigned address by qsys (platform designer) to control any block on FPGA side using ARM (Linux).

[image: image that somehow explains the system]

I want to change the content of the memory block in FPGA part using ARM part (With a software program) while the FPGA part is configured. How can that be done?

The HW system on its own works (it was tested and simulated), but the memory content cannot be changed after the HW system is configured. I have to change .mif file, compile and reconfigure the HW in order to change the memory content now. I think there must be a software solution for that which I don't know yet.

Comment: Do not hesitate to comment if you have question regarding the question (if you need more information)

Comment: Memory file initialization, check...  you want to change the memory "while" the FPGA is being configured?  nope, not gonna happen...  Do you, possibly, mean "after" the FPGA is configured?

Comment: Yes, I mean after FPGA is configured

Answer (score 2):

Second answer as the comments are flowing off the page....

First find out how the memory is configured:

- Address range on the bus
- Data width
- Byte enables?

Then the best solution is to simulate accessing your memory.
You may have a problem there. I have used mainly Xilinx but on e.g. the zynq system you have to fork out a decent amount of money to get a simulation model of the CPU system.

Alternative is to build yourself a bus access module!
That is a simple behavioral module that generates AXI read and write cycles. It does not have to do all possible AXI transfer: just the basic single beat read and write.

If you plan to do *any* work with AXI it is time well spend as you can use it again and again. Other advantages:

- You don't have to spend hours working through a manual how to connect/use it.
- You can expand it in in due time to make more complex cycles.

Disadvantage: It may not be 100% AXI compliant and at some time you will have to find out if the bug you are having is in the module or in the test-bench.

You might want to look [at this webpage](https://www.verilog.pro/axi.html) where there seems to be a free AXI bus model.

Answer (score 0):

ok, well... How do you plan to change it? (somewhat rhetorical).. you have an ARM...  is it part of the FPGA or an external interface (i.e. via pins)?  Assuming its part of the FPGA, or even not, can't you write a SW program that understands the addresses?  FPGA design, you do that, and you have a memory mapped address space (by design) that has a address relative to the ARM.. hopefully, something directly addressed for ease.  Forgive me if I over-simplify this, but, I think this is just an ARM, and a memory, residing on the AMBA bus(?) ARM is Master, memory is Slave(?) that  receives AMBA transactions via Slave, and then, via a protcol-bridge, satisfies the memory transactions (i.e. a transfer function) to put your new values in memory.... Maybe I am missing something?

can you post a design drawing?

Comment: Yes, it has a soc containing FPGA and ARM, there is a bridge between them as you mentioned. And you are right, I am using ARM as a master and FPGA memory block as a slave. And it is possible to reach the memory block using the address of that block relative to ARM, I got it.

Comment: But the problem now is what should be data format that is sent to that address?

Comment: For example if the .mif file contains 300 rows of 90 (as well as memory block) bit long words, how should I send data for it?

Comment: ok, good... so, is this a SW problem or a HW problem?  Sorry, had to ask, as it's the classic question :)  you have an ARM SW program that addresses the memory to modify the contents... let's back up for a second.  Have you simulated your FPGA design?  Either directly to the memory without the ARM, or Instruction set simulation for the ARM?  I think, step one is, simulation with the ARM eliminated, and make sure your AMBA bus transactions are translated properly... then, once satisfied, introduce the ARM again with your SW.  Simulation is your friend

Comment: depends on your memory configuration... don't over-think this... memory that is 16-bits wide expects (typically) 16 bit data, and in your case, via AMBA.  forget the ARM and make that work (make a TB component.. behavioral... for the ARM).

Comment: i am hoping you are simulating this first :)

Comment: Ok, I will try to edit the content of a small memory block using a program on ARM to make a simulation, you are right, I never tried that before

Comment: The problem is with software, hardware is by itself (with initial .mif content) is working. I just have a software problem

Comment: And I would be really happy if you could help more :)

Comment: To be clear, I assume this is all in sim, and not on HW.  You should always, always, always, (did I say ALWAYS?) sim first... if you skipped this, reconsider.  You have no visibility in HW.. simulation shows you EVERYTHING.... save electrical issue after the fact, get your logic correct first, and the best method to that is simulation.  This post will show up in a lot of smart people's inbox tomorrow, and we will help you solve this, but testbench first, emulate the ARM processor to eliminate you HW design, then if that works, explore your SW

Comment: Thanks.. look, we have all been there, to some extent...  as frustrating as your project is right now, school or work, either way, you will learn from this :)

Comment: Thanks, I made the HW simulation but not the SW one, now I will do it too :)

Comment: oh, HW works... ok.  ARM has an ISS ( I think) for your TB.  high-level to test your interface.  if you are sure your HW is working, we might want to see your SW

Comment: Yes, I had to mention it in the question that SW is problem now